# What is the key difference between Stochastic Gradient Descent and Hamiltonian Monte Carlo optimization

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, monte-carlo, gradient-descent

I'm a student of machine learning and consequently also a student of physics, mathematical optimization and statistics. One of the most elegant optimization routines I have bumped into in my studies is the Hamiltonian Monte Carlo (HMC) which utilizes Hamiltonian mechanics in order to improve the convergence of the Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)-method by utilizing gradient information. My level of understanding of the HMC method is still on the shallow end, but it somehow resembles a bit the Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)-method, at least from a high-level perspective.

**My question thus is:** What is the key difference between the SGD and HMC methods? I bet of course there are technical differences, but on a fundamental conceptual level what is the difference? Or is the basic high-level idea the same: "Utilize gradient descent with random component to avoid local optima"

Comment: MCMC methods are typically used to sample from posterior probability distributions that are intractable to sample from (the partition function is infeasible to compute). In this case computing things like the maximum likelihood is infeasible as well. Stochastic Gradient descent is a numerical method for function optimization (typically optimizing a parameterized function) in which a closed form of the function's gradient must be feasible to compute. The only sampling that goes on is random sampling from a dataset we are optimizing the function on, to avoid optimizations over the whole daraset

Comment: @dylan7 thank you for your help :) I was however more or less aware of these technical details already. I think I was thinking more about the relationship between these methods because they seemed very similar. Were they independently developed or was the other inspired by the first etc.? Could you, broadly speaking, say that HMC is the same as SGD (both are iterative gradient utilizing stochastic methods), but HMC works also with "problems containing not so nice integrals".